# Typescript cannot find name error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently developing a application with the Angular2, i created a small private object which will have the firstName and the lastName when i try to transpile the file from typescript to javascript i am getting an error stating

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firstName'

My code is

```
export class AppComponent {

public ContactDetail = {firstName="xander",lastName ="xmen"};

}
```

Is their an possible way to solve this solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get a bit more familiar with the `TypeScript` syntax.
It starts from the `JavaScript` syntax, so your object should look like this:

```
ContactDetail = {
  firstName:"xander",
  lastName:"xmen"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix errors with your syntax, you can use:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public ContactDetail: {firstName:string, lastName:string} = {firstName: "xander", lastName:"xmen"};
}
```

But to make your architecture more flexible, you can do something like this:

```
export class ContactDetail {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string;
}

export class AppComponent {
    public ContactDetail: ContactDetail
}

// USAGE
var myContact = new AppComponent;
myContact.ContactDetail = {firstName: 'xander', lastName: 'xmen'}
```